# What does incarnation mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I know that incarnation is the embodiment but in this line it seems to me confusing.

> In comparison with its earlier incarnation, modern ECT is virtually
>   unrecognizable.

Here, ECT mean Electroconvulsive Therapy.

Comment: *Incarnation* in this sentence means "embodiment". You will have to explain why that is confusing to you.

Comment: Here, "Earlier incarnation" = "previous version"

Comment: Have you looked at the English Language Learners site?  http://ell.stackexchange.com I think it might be a better place for answering your questions. However, it's hard to answer a question that is just "explain to me what this means." It helps us if you try to say what you're having trouble with, or what your best guess is about what the sentence means.

Answer (score 0):

As deadrat points out in a comment above, the meaning of *incarnation* that the cited sentence seems to be trying to convey is approximately "version." Here is the relevant definition from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **incarnation** *n* (14c) ... **3 :** a particular physical form : VERSION {TV and movie *incarnations* of the story}

So in the sentence that the OP cites, the author is saying that the current form of ECT and the earlier form of the same therapy have so little in common that an observer would hardly recognize one as the predecessor of the other.